# enum with string and list?

Tags: java, string, enums

Is it possible to write an enum in java as below?

```
public enum SomeEnum{

ADDRESS("someData", arraylist);
}
```

Basically is it possible to keep list inside Enum ?

Comment: You could wait till january 3rd to stop following your resolution to search before asking. Come on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define like below, Since Enums are constant, you need to pass your array list in compilation time.

```
public enum SomeEnum{
  String name;
  ArrayList data;

SomeEnum(String name, ArrayList data) {
  this.name = name;
  this.data=data;
}

  ADDRESS("someData", new ArrayList()); // pass your arraylist here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, [Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) is just like a class. It can have attribute and methods.

Comment: Karnaow , could u please tell me how can i write ENUMCONSTANT("someValue", listOfValues);

Comment: @user755806: Just go through the mentioned link. Try something and  come back if you face any issue.

Comment: @ZouZou: Thanks, not worried about downvote. Just hate it when they gift them without a reason.